# intelephense error on VS Code: Expected type 'string'. Found 'string[]'

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intelephense

Suppose the following piece of code:

```
<?php
declare (strict_types = 1);

define('SOURCE_PATH', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\atlantis\ProductImages\\');

$dest = explode('\\', SOURCE_PATH);
$dest[count($dest) - 2] = 'ToUpload';
$dest = implode('\\', $dest);

function transfer(string $file)
{
    global $dest;

    if (!@chdir($dest)) {
        mkdir($dest);
        chdir($dest);
    }

    // ...
}

function compress(string $path)
{
    global $dest;

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open(dirname($dest, 1) . '\\' . explode('\\', SOURCE_PATH)[count(explode('\\', SOURCE_PATH)) - 2] . '.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    // ...
}
```

So, intelephense on VS Code keeps complaining about `Expected type 'string'. Found 'string[]'.` on all four instances where I use `$dest` in my functions...

What's that intelephense doesn't like about my code? Note that page runs fine... And what's that string[] type? `implode()` returns a string, so what's the problem here?

EDIT: It's most probably a bug of intelephense...

I calculated `$dest` like this:

`$dest = dirname(SOURCE_PATH, 1) . '\ToUpload\\';`

which doesn't involve `explode()`ing, and indeed the ***error*** is gone... So somehow intelephense fails to take into consideration that `implode()` returns a string and not an array...

Actually, I filed a bug report on github and I'm awaiting Mewburn's response on this... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Global variables can be a little bit wonky in intelephense, [an issue](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1365) already exists to improve the support. In this specific case, the type that is inferred is determined by the first assignment. Since that is the explode statement, it'll assume `$dest` is an array of strings.

There are a couple of solutions to this:

- Make sure to intelephense what the type of `$dest` is with comments.

  ```php
  function transfer(string $file)
  {
      /** @var string $dest */
      global $dest;
  }
  ```
- Make sure the first assignment of `$dest` actually is a string:

  ```php
  $tempdest = explode('\\', SOURCE_PATH);
  $tempdest[count($tempdest) - 2] = 'ToUpload';
  $dest = implode('\\', $dest);
  ```

Comment: Is there any way to have intelephense work properly with a global array containing both strings and ints?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's because the implode parameters have been changed.

https://www.php.net/manual/de/migration74.deprecated.php
says the following:

> **Implode with historical parameter order** Passing parameters to implode() in reverse order is deprecated, use implode($glue, $parts)
> instead of implode($parts, $glue).